# My artifact seems to big to be deployed by maven. What can I do?

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins

My maven 3.0.3 build has a `-Xmx1G` and `-XX:MaxPermSize=500M` set in Jenkins. however, when I do a deploy, I always get

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:94)
    at sun.net.www.http.PosterOutputStream.write(PosterOutputStream.java:61)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:492)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.putTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:411)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:392)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.putTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.put(StreamWagon.java:163)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:825)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.put(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:465)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:278)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:215)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:480)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Artifact to deploy is `283M`big. what can I do to have it correctly deployed ?

Comment: @bmargulies maven is version `3.0.3`

Comment: @Nicolas and with maven 3.0.4 ?

Comment: @olamy here I'm named "Riduidel" :-) And I haven't yet tried with maven 3.0.4, as it's my Jenkins machine that do the job (but i'll try now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by [this bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/WAGON-272). As suggested in the link, simply use webdav to deploy.

Consider doing the following:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-webdav</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>  
    </plugin>
  </build>
  ...
  <distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>sample-project.website</id>
        <url>dav:https://dav.sample.com/sites/sample-project</url>
    </site>
  </distributionManagement>
  ...
</project>
```

I've had this issue before. I believe it happens only with artifacts with a size of >= 256 MB.

After switching to the webdav deployment method, you can also reduce your memory settings. (if you've specifically modified them just due to the memory issue during the deployment).

Comment: this technique is likely not needed if you are using 3.0.4

Answer (score 1):

This answer to say simply that @olamy was right : upgrading to maven 3.0.4 solved that issue.

Comment: or @carlspring - he linked to the bug, explained the issue and provided the workaround.

Comment: @eis I accept carlspring answer cause, well, i can ask my colleagues to migrate their maven, but I can't ask the whole interwebz to do so :-)

Comment: I believe it was actually Brett Porter who pointed out it was fixed in 3.0.4, which I didn't know myself. Anyhow, glad to be of help! :)

Comment: @carlspring well ... The first mention of 3.0.4 I saw was by olamy (also a maven comitter BTW)

Comment: Yeah, I know him and some of the other committers - I am regularly on their IRC. Cheers!